# Request report with parameters

Tags: jasper-reports, report

I want to create a report with *JasperReports* with multiple parameters, the report is generated correctly when the user passes all the parameters but nothing is generated when one parameter is missed i use this request

```sql
  SELECT
     t.*,
     u."name" AS username,
     c."name" AS componentName,
     s."designation" AS statusName,
     pr."name" AS priorityName,
     p."name" AS projectName
FROM
     "component" c INNER JOIN "ticket" t ON c."id" = t."component_id"
     INNER JOIN "personne" u ON t."personne_id" = u."id"
     INNER JOIN "status" s ON t."status_id" = s."id"
     INNER JOIN "priority" pr ON t."priority_id" = pr."id"
     INNER JOIN "project" p ON c."project_id" = p."id"
WHERE
     pr.name = $P{priority}
and u.login = $P{userLogin}
and s.designation = $P{status}
and t.creation_date between $P{start} and $P{end}
and c.name = $P{componenet}
```

Please can you help me to generate the report even where there is one parameter missed?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is setting the **When No Data** setting on the report to display the **no data** band when empty (make sure you add the band),  Or maybe ** all sections, No data**

Comment: yes i verified it i get in the rapport the title of the columns but what i really want is to synchronise with a filter in in IHM of my application to extract the report.In fact, in this filter when the user didn't choose any parameters by default all the list appears i would like to extract exactly the same thing but in my report with the request that i used when i didn't choose any parameters only the name of the columns appears

Comment: in other words i would like if the user didn't enter any parameter i give (%) to all the parameters to extract the list

Answer (score 0):

do you want outer joins?  or you may choose a structure like this:

```
and ( u.login = $P{userLogin} or $P{userLogin} is null )
```

for each line

Answer (score 0):

You can control the where clause in java class before generate the report.
1.In java u can check whether the parameter is null or not, then do small validation such as

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(priority)){
        sb.append(" AND pr.name = "+priority);
    }
```

2.do for every other condition for `u.login, s.designation`
3.after that u can pass `reportParam.put("sqlQuery", sb.toString());`

4.the in ireport simply change your query

```
WHERE
pr.name = $P{priority}
and u.login = $P{userLogin}
and s.designation = $P{status}
and t.creation_date between $P{start} and $P{end}
and c.name = $P{componenet}
```

to

```
WHERE 1=1 $P!{sqlQuery}
```

now you dont need to worry about the `null`, since it will ignore the condition in java class.

Comment: thanks for your responses i tested them but the report is generated empty now when the user dont't choose one parameter but i what i want is to choose all th cases possibles for this parameter  when he didn't pass anything i tried for example WHERE
pr.name like('%', $P{priority},'%') but i have an error please help me

Comment: i think you want `Where  pr.name like(coalesce($P{priority},'%')` this will looks to see if $P{priority} is null then return %

Comment: thanks for the response i tested that but i don't have the result that i have wished.In fact, i have an interface wich contains list of tickets with filters by default when i don't choose any filter, all the list appears i would like in the extraction of this list to synchronize with what is appeared in the interface. But i have a problem:When i don't choose any filter or one of the filter in the report i have only the name of the columns there is no ticket in the report please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default values for every parameter or use this query:-

```
     SELECT
 t.*,
 u."name" AS username,
 c."name" AS componentName,
 s."designation" AS statusName,
 pr."name" AS priorityName,
 p."name" AS projectName
FROM
 "component" c INNER JOIN "ticket" t ON c."id" = t."component_id"
 INNER JOIN "personne" u ON t."personne_id" = u."id"
 INNER JOIN "status" s ON t."status_id" = s."id"
 INNER JOIN "priority" pr ON t."priority_id" = pr."id"
 INNER JOIN "project" p ON c."project_id" = p."id"
WHERE
 (pr.name = $P{priority} or $P{priority}  is null)
  and (u.login = $P{userLogin} or $P{userLogin}  is null)
  and (s.designation = $P{status}  or $P{status} is null )
  and t.creation_date between $P{start}  and $P{end}
  and (c.name = $P{componenet} or $P{componenet}  is null)
```